# XAMPP VM and text editors

Tags: terminal, virtualization, apache, php

I recently installed XAMPP for OS X (XAMPP VM PHP 7.2.1) which now virtualizes the entire box for obvious benefits of higher security. Although I admire the new concept and see its benefits, I cannot put my head around one thing that puzzles me.

I would like to enable the PHPMyAdmin tool, which requires me to change a file, based on this well described set of instructions:

http://localhost:8080/dashboard/docs/access-phpmyadmin-remotely.html

This document basically describes the steps needed to relax the security concept that prevents directly accessing the PHPMyAdmin login. It asks you to edit the /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf file in order to allow access to PHPMyAdmin. One can get to the file system via the stack manager. In this file, the following block:

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
  AllowOverride AuthConfig
  Require local
  ...
```

needs to be changed into:

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
  AllowOverride AuthConfig
  Require all granted
  ...
```

Strangely, and I am extremely puzzled by it and cannot actually believe it, I seem to not be able to find neither pico, vi, vim, or nano (all very standard editors in any Linux distribution) on this virtual machine. Since I am on the VM, I have no access to tools on my own machine (i.e. everything in /Applications).

Did I overlook something? What is going on?

Comment: The link you shared is a link to localhost, which means only you can access it. It would be nice if you share a link from the web.

Comment: Here: https://www.lexar.com/dashboard/docs/access-phpmyadmin-remotely.html However, my question about the missing editor is actually not really related to the details in that document.

Comment: If it's not related at all, you can just remove that from the question. Otherwise, please replace the link in the question with this one.

Comment: did you find the answer? I am running into the same issue where the VM does not seem equipped with any of the default text editors.
klanomath's answer looks great, except step3 relies on nano being installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'solved' the issue by returning back to the non-VM version of XAMPP but then had to leave this solution altogether for other reasons (I was not able to scale from XAMPP). So, I used HomeBrew (yes, I am a Mac User) to install Apache, PHP (actaully 3 different version for different purposes), PHPMyAdmin, MariaDB and MongoDB manually and hand-configure it.

I realised that these pre-build stacks are good and useful if you do not want to dive in and change them (or bend them). I will, in the future spend a bit more time an do it that way.

Thanks for all the feedback and attention.

Answer (score 7):

As the documentation suggests, you need to locate and edit the file: `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`

The hard part for me was locating this file. The solution I found was to ensure the stack volume was mounted:

[image]

From there, you can click the explore button, which will open `/opt/lampp/`. You can then navigate to `etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf` from the Finder window that is opened and edit with any editor you want.

Alternatively, once the drive is mounted, you should be able to access the volume through Finder:

[image]

Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should open xampp control panel click "open terminal" in the "general" tab, then do the following steps :

1. apt update
2. apt install vim
3. vim /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
4. change Require local  to Require all granted
5. restart apache in service tab
6. open phpmyadmin

Comment: After searching for hours, your post solved the issue.

Many thanks!!!

People might need some help on VIM, that's the only survivor:

See the best answer for all the VIM commands to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-do-i-exit-the-vim-editor

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the file directly from the host:

- Start XAMPP (VM version)
- Mount the data volume:

  [image]
- Open Terminal on your host (Not the terminal accessible from XAMPP) and enter:

  ```
  sudo nano ~/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
  ```
- change:

  ```
  <Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require local
    ...
  ```

  to:

  ```
  <Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require all granted
    ...
  ```

  and save the changes!
- Start Apache and MySQL
- Open a browser on the host and enter:

  ```
  http://<IP-VM>/phpmyadmin/
  ```

  The default IP-VM appears to be 192.168.64.2.

Answer (score -1):

try this, it just worked for me with xampp vm on os x

```
apt-get install vim
```

Comment: Where is apt-get ?

Comment: @Mark- the `fink` package manager has the `apt-get` command.

Answer (score -1):

Try to update apt-get by using

```
apt-get update
```

After that you can try to install

```
apt-get install vim
```